# IndexOutOfRangeException - Reading through a file

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

So I am trying to read through a file and I have index set as a counter so I can move from character to character in the file to find the index where the °s are at. I keep getting IndexOutOfRangeException even though I have no clue what is wrong.

```
 Dim chr As String
    Dim c1 As String
    Dim c2 As String
    Dim c3 As String
    Static index As Integer = -1
    index += 1
    chr = numDat(index)

    While Asc(chr) <> 176
        index += 1
        chr = numDat(index)
    End While
```

I am getting the error at the index in chr = numDat(index). Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that numDat is a string that has read in the whole file already.

```
numDat = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path + fileName)
```

Comment: No idea what this is, but it sure isn't VB6 so your tags are wrong.  maybe The Great Pretender VB.Net since it has a `+=` in it?

Comment: @bob77 I honestly do not know. This is the first time I am taking this class called Advanced Visual Basic.

Comment: this is vb.net, not vb6.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That's where the confusion comes from, VB.Net is not "VB" but another thing altogether relabeled as such in hopes of market acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all occurrences of `°` like this:

```
numDat = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path + fileName)
Dim index As Integer = numDat.IndexOf("°")
While index <> -1
    Debug.Print(index)
    index = numDat.IndexOf("°", index + 1)
End While
```